# Will Keras multi-output model always produce conflict-free results?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, prediction

I built 2 models with Keras for the same dataset: one predicting class A only and the other predicting class B only. The models had the same architecture:

- a number of hidden Dense() layers with ReLU activation,
- one Dense() layer in the output with sigmoid activation.

Each model was trained to achieve precision at ca. 0.77, but quite obviously there were conflicts in predictions where both models produced positive predictions for the same sample.

Next I built another Keras model with the same architecture as before, but bigger layer sizes and triple output to predict class A or B or (not A and not B). From the tests I have run so far it seems like the model always produce 1 positive and 2 negatives for every sample from the test set, which was good, but my question is: can I be sure that this always be the case? And if yes would that be a result of the training or some property of the model layers?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide us your model architecture to better understand your networks.

This is probably linked to the way you train your model. When training a model with 1 output of size 3 with "A xor B xor None" your labels are 1-hot vectors. Thus your model learn to output 1 to only one of these values.

Moreover, classification models often ended with a [`Softmax`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax) layer.
This layer as the property of pushing the maximal value of a tensor toward 1 while pulling the others toward 0 (making sure that all values sum to 1).

Comment: Thanks, I added a brief description of the model architecture which seems to confirm your initial guesses.